# How to combine the search string result with WHERE conditions in SQL query in PHP?

Tags: php, sql

I have PHP file with if else condition which work as follows.Below is just example i am working, you can get whole php script below please see,

I want to allow the user to use both search string and select option so that user can easily further filter out the search result.

Example, if a user searched "Nutt", then all rows having "Nutt" is returned and displayed, but if user further want to see only rows with `CountryName=USA` then it is not possible in my case as i am diverting it to else case for the `CountryName`.

```
if(search_string is in POST){

SQL query which search for string in all column varible

example,

SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  `tbl_main_lead_info` 
WHERE 
  `FirstName` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `LastName` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Company` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Website` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Designation` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Linkedin` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Email` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Phone` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `City` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `State` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `Country` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `TechArea` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `FirmType` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `FirmSize` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `LeadDescription` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `OwnerNotes` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' 
  OR `AdminNotes` 
ORDER BY 
  FirstName ASC, 
  LastName ASC

}else{

else is executed when the user use other drop down options instead of inputting search string

For example,

SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info WHERE LeadStatus = $lead_status AND  Company = $_POST['company_name'];

}
```

Below is my complete PHP code. Please see and guide me.

```
<?php 

        // send a JSON encoded array to client

        include('connection.php');

        if(isset($_POST['search_string']) and strlen(trim($_POST['search_string'])) > 0){

            $search_string = $_POST['search_string'];

            // Empty array for collecting search results
            $search_result_array = array();


            $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_main_lead_info` WHERE `FirstName` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `LastName` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Company` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Website` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Designation` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Linkedin` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Email` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Phone` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `City` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `State` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `Country` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `TechArea` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `FirmType` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `FirmSize` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `LeadDescription` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `OwnerNotes` LIKE '%".$search_string."%' OR `AdminNotes` ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC ";

            $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                        // Word found
                        array_push($search_result_array, $row);             

                }

                // print_r($search_result_array);

                print_r(json_encode($search_result_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));


            }   


        }else{

            $sqlFlag = 0;

            function queryDelimiter(){
                global $sqlFlag;
                if ($sqlFlag == 0){
                    $sqlFlag = 1;
                    return ' WHERE ';
                }else{
                    return ' AND ';
                }
            }

            $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

            if(isset($_POST['lead_status']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_status'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadStatus = '".$_POST['lead_status']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['lead_owner']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_owner'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LeadAddedBy = '".$_POST['lead_owner']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['company_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['company_name'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Company = '".$_POST['company_name']."'";
            }       

            if(isset($_POST['tech_area']) and strlen(trim($_POST['tech_area'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."TechArea = '".$_POST['tech_area']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['firm_size']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_size'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmSize = '".$_POST['firm_size']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['firm_type']) and strlen(trim($_POST['firm_type'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."FirmType = '".$_POST['firm_type']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['country_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['country_name'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."Country = '".$_POST['country_name']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['state_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['state_name'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."State = '".$_POST['state_name']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['city_name']) and strlen(trim($_POST['city_name'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."City = '".$_POST['city_name']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['start_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['start_date'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."LastContactDate >='".$_POST['start_date']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['end_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['end_date'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."NextContactDate <= '".$_POST['end_date']."'";
            }

            if(isset($_POST['lead_added_on_date']) and strlen(trim($_POST['lead_added_on_date'])) > 0){
                $selectSQL .= queryDelimiter()."DATE(LeadAddedOn) = '".$_POST['lead_added_on_date']."'";
            }

            $selectSQL .= " ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC";

            $result_array = array();

            $result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    array_push($result_array, $row);

                }

            }

            // print_r($result_array);

            // header("Content-Type: application/json");

            // print_r($result_array);

            print_r(json_encode($result_array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

            // $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info as M, tbl_campaign_info as C";

        }

        $conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: That query is very bad and unperformant. Create a fulltext index and search in that.

Answer (score 0):

When you put user input directly to SQL it becomes open to SQL Injection that can delete all your database. Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) instead

---

With `CountryName=USA`: explode on `=`, check if first half is valid column name, and add second part as search param

```
function addCondition(
    string $columnName,
    string $name,
    array &$conditions,
    array &$params,
    string $comparator = '=',
    bool $isDate = false
) {
    static $i = 0;

    if (!isset($_POST[$name]) || strlen(trim($_POST[$name])) == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if ($isDate) {
        $columnName = "Date(`{$columnName}`)";
    } else {
        $columnName = "`{$columnName}`";
    }

    $conditions[] = "{$columnName} {$comparator} :value{$i}";
    $params[":value{$i}"] = $_POST[$name];
    $i++;
}

function addCustomCondition(array &$conditions, array &$params) {
    if (empty($_POST['filter']) || strpos($_POST['filter'], '=') === false) {
        return;
    }

    /** @var PDO $pdo */
    $q = $pdo->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
    $q->execute();
    $columns = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

    list($column, $value) = explode('=', $_POST['filter']);

    if (!in_array($column, $columns)) {
        return;
    }

    $conditions[] = "{$column} = :value{$column}";
    $params[":value{$column}"] = $value;
}

$conditions = [];
$params = [];
$selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info";

addCondition('LeadStatus', 'lead_status', $conditions, $params);
addCondition('LeadAddedBy', 'lead_owner', $conditions, $params);
addCondition('Company', 'company_name', $conditions, $params);
// [...]
addCondition('LastContactDate', 'start_date', $conditions, $params, '>=');
addCondition('NextContactDate', 'end_date', $conditions, $params, '<=');
addCondition('LeadAddedOn', 'lead_added_on_date', $conditions, $params, '=', true);

addCustomCondition($conditions, $params);

if (empty($conditions)) {
    // Maybe you can allow filter whole table, then do not throw error
    throw new Exception('Noting filtering');
}

$selectSQL .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $conditions);

$selectSQL .= " ORDER BY FirstName ASC, LastName ASC";

/** @var PDO $pdo */
$statement = $pdo->prepare($selectSQL);
$statement->execute($params);
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, i want to know that if the user does not enter any search string then will it work normally with search string parameters? are you using search string `$name` as search string

Comment: that search string i was searching as substring in values of rows

Comment: also can we do this without PDO connection

Comment: No, `$name` is passed to function as variable. It's example code, change it as you like, you can even drop PDO usage if needed

Comment: but search string with WHERE <condition> is not working

Comment: Plz add some comments so that i easily get how your code is approaching to the solution of problem

Comment: In which place your code is comparing for the search condition if the user tries to search the substring in the rows

Comment: Error of `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Noting filtering in C:\wamp64\www\CRM\server\searchso.php on line 80` when the user tries to search without inputting any search string or select option

Comment: @RinkuYadav Error is thrown by `throw new Exception('Noting filtering');`